# Blade : select option inside foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

Having a `collection` of `departments` returned from DB.

I'm trying to display this list within a `select` in my `.blade` file, like this :

```
<select name="department" data-required="1" class="form-control">
     @foreach ($departments as $dep)
           <option value="{{ $dep->id }}" > {{ $dep->label }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

And now I am getting this error :

> syntax error, unexpected '$dep' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' (View: /....../...blade.php) In the option line

[image]

But if I remove the `"{{ $dep->id }}"` from the value attribute of the `option`, everything works fine !

I am unable to figure it out ! And I am sure that I have an `id` attribute.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your error stack?

Comment: there is a share button share from there

Comment: Try Changing your syntax from {{ }} to {!! !!}. There might be special characters in label.
`<option value="{{!! $dep->id !!}}" > {{!! $dep->label !!}}</option>`

Comment: var_dump your $dep->id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Remove the `""` from this line :

```
 <option value={{ $dep->id }} > {{ $dep->label }}</option>
```

Comment: Thnx ! But strangely this is working! Would you please explain why?

Comment: it's Blade render matter, it can't evaluate the expression inside the " "

Answer (score 0):

It might happen because of your view cache so
Try after clearing your view cache, Because your code is perfect and it should work.
Try clearing your view cache

```
php artisan view:clear

php artisan view:cache
```

To clear other cache

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan view:clear

php artisan view:cache

php artisan config:cache
```